# Is possible restart a suspended system remotely?

Tags: networking, remote, suspend, remote-desktop, remote-control

For Ubuntu and Fedora based on GUI - both as remote clients - in a laptop (and even PC) is possible execute *remotely* through either `SSH` or `Remmina` the following command:

- `sleep 15 && systemctl suspend`

The system can be restarted by opening the laptop's lid or pressing any key. Of course it must be accomplished locally and is practically mandatory do the login again. Until here all ok.

Consider a special policy of the company/university/client to suspend the system but for a special case is not possible restart it locally.

I did do a research and I found the `rtcwake` command but it works locally and is based on scheduled time. It is very useful **but** what about if is need it to restart the system in a specific time, prior of the scheduled time, while it is suspended and *remotely*?.

Is possible restart the suspended system remotely?. And how?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for Wake On LAN?

Comment: Or for PC, you have a: power up after black-out (usually named differently, a BIOS setting): the PC turn on if you give electricity. And then some smart-sockets (which often can be controlled remotely). But laptops lacks such functionality.

Comment: @Panki it seems it would be. Giacomo interesting that feature.

Comment: @Manuel Jordan on Fedora 39 i'm able to restart a suspended system remotely with WOL feature. It has only to be enabled in BIOS.

Comment: WOL works for me on a computer running Debian. (Also for one running Windows, but that's out of scope here and only mentioned for reference.) Is the question specifically about starting a laptop remotely, or just systems in general?